# how to crop to square thubmnail using gm for node.js

Tags: graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

trying to figure out how to crop to square using graphicmagick for node.js with imagemagick , but how do I pass the ^ flag to the thumbnail method so that it crops

var gm = require('gm')
    .subClass({imageMagick: true}); // Enable ImageMagick integration.

```
gm(inPath).thumb('200','200^').scale('5%').scale('2000%').write(outPath, function(err, results){

    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so it looks like I had to use the `thumbnail` method instead of `thumb` if I wanted to pass in the ^ in the resize

e.g.

`gm(inPath).thumbnail('200','200^')`